# How to use crawled output of first scrapy spider for next scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and I want to do the following: 
- I want to crawl a homepage and extract some specific listings
- with these listings I want to adjust the url and crawl the new web page

**Crawling First URL**

```
class Spider1:

  start_urls = 'https://page1.org/'  
  
  def parse(self, response):
    listings = response.css('get-listings-here').extract()
```

**Crawling Second URL**

```
class Spider2:

  start_urls = 'https://page1.org/listings[output_of_Spider1]'  
  
  def parse(self, response):
    final_data = response.css('get-needed_data').extract()

    items['final'] = final_data
    yield items
```

Maybe it is also possible within one spider, I am not sure. But what would be the best solution for it? 
Thank you!

Comment: This is a very common use case. Please work through the scrapy tutorial if you haven't already: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

After extracting all links from your selector you need to yield Request to those links and add callback where you will receive HTML response

```
def parse(self,response):
    yield Request(‘http://amazon.com/',callback=self.page)

def page(self,response):
    ## your new page html response
```

you can replace your extracted link with this amazon link.

Reference to the documentation [scrapy Request](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)

Comment: could you may give me an example how it would look like?